# Differences between "Build" and "Build Extension Configuration" in Visual Studio SQL Server Database Project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I haven't been able to understand what are the differences between these two build actions for the database project available amongst Visual Studio project templates.
I just know that build extension configuration allows me to compile some files that, viceversa with build action, raise some errors.

Why is that?
Thanks in advance

[image: Build Actions in Visual Studio]